# Heavy bike lock mount on a carbon frame

Tags: lock

I have a foldable Abus Bordo 6500 which weights around 1.7kg. It came with a sturdy, rubber based case that can be mounted using bottle cage mounts.

Is this OK to do so on a carbon frame, or does it open up risk? The bike in question has 2x bottle mounts and I was hoping to put this on the seat tube.

At the moment I am chucking it in my backpack, but a bike mounted solution might be a little neater for days I don't have my pack.

(I did search but most questions on this topic relate to pressure clamps for D locks whereas my issue is a bottle mount.)

Thanks

Comment: Better ask the maker of the bike, as bottles weigh between 520 and 770g when full and mounting points are designed for that weight.

Comment: @Carel 1l bottles aren't rare, mine are Zefal but other major brands do them. They might not be widely used on race bikes but they're common for endurance riding

Comment: Do be aware that those folding bike locks are vulnerable to attack by an open-sided nut splitter.  Its quiet too, except for the one instant where the pin gives way with a bang.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zs8uyPsDaw0   So your nice expensive carbon bike still can't be left alone for long in risky areas.

Comment: @Criggie: I thought they’d already improved the Bordo to address this weakness? But maybe this is already the improved version (with the hardened steel washer he shows in the end). In any case, a U-Lock will usually be lighter&stronger, though less versatile.

Answer (score 3):

In general strapping 1.7 kg of mass to a CFC frame is not a problem. CFC frames are actually quite robust. However, I would be concerned about attaching the case to water bottle mounts. Water bottle mounts, brake mounts etc on CFC frames are constructed with an aluminum insert epoxied in a hole in the CFC. These can work loose if subjected to too much cyclic stress.

[This Hambini YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0MKuzeZA0k) explains how the inserts work (and how to fix them.

If the case comes with straps, I'd use those instead. Put tape on the frame where the case and straps touch it to stop paint being worn off by movement of the case.